# Wordpress categories hierachy issue

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with my catogories in my custom post type. I am trying to do a basic apartments booking system. I created custom post called Apartments and then I added a categories. The category tree looks like this:

Countries
- Spain
-- Barcelona
-- Madrid
- Greece
-- Athenes

and so on.

I want to achive effect when the user enter to the apartment in Barcelona, the higher category will be displayed in header (in this example Spain). When the user eneter to the apartment in Athenes the Greece category should be in header. I tried solution that I have found on stack but it does not work for me.

```
        $category = get_the_category();

        foreach ($category as $cat) {
          echo $cat->name;
        }
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $category[0]->term_id, 'category' );
        $direct_parent_id = $ancestors[0];

        echo $direct_parent_id;
```

Only the second category is displayed and as you can see the categories are displayed in alphabetical order instead of hierarchical.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thank you in advance for directions

Comment: where you added the provided code?

Comment: I my post template.

Comment: how many categories related to one post( for ex., to the post of  Barcelona )?

Comment: The post always has a few categories. For example Barcelona has a categories: countries, Spain, Barcelona, popular. And when I am reviewing this post I want the name of the parent category (Spain) to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Function [`get_the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) returns the object WP_Term. So, it's possible to get the `parent` from that object.

[Used this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5474034/8053001), in your case it will be:

First, add this function to your `functions.php` file of active theme/child theme to have access to it from other files of theme/child theme:

```
function get_deep_child_category( $categories )
{
    $maxId = 0;
    $maxKey = 0;
    foreach ( $categories as $key => $value )
    {
        if ( $value->parent > $maxId )
        {
            $maxId = $value->term_id;
            $maxKey = $key;
        }
    }

    return $categories[$maxKey];
}
```

**Note:** in some cases this will not work as expected. For example, if your post has category Some_category, which is child of Some_category_parent, and the Some_category_parent was created after your Spain category, then, this will return the category Some_category.

Next step will be to use it. For example, in your post template:

```
$categories = get_the_category();

if ( $categories ){
    $deep_child = get_deep_child_category( $categories );

    echo get_cat_name($deep_child->parent);
}
```

After getting the deepest category object with function `get_deep_child_category`, we got the `ID` of it's parent category. [`get_cat_name()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_cat_name/) returned the name of parent category using it's `ID`. In your case, it's Spain.